# Clicking on a tag gives no result

Tags: support, tagging

When I click on a tag on the main site, for example on the LuaTeX-Tag, I get to the page: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luatex. But the page is "empty" (no answers) except for the following message:

```
You are on the Featured tab.
There are no questions with an active bounty at the moment.
Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?
```

Is this on purpose? I am confused by this behavior.

---

Edit:

Some more on this bug (I wonder why the bug-tag was removed). The tags page remember some last visited page (featured, faq, ...) so clicking on a tag gives a different behavior in different circumstances. The URL I gave above depends on some internal state that is not visible to the user. I am pretty sure this is not the desired behavior of this SE site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, "You are on the Featured tab." This means that you're looking at featured questions only at the moment, and there's no featured question tagged [luatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luatex). Just click on one of "newest", "faq", "votes", "active" or "unanswered", according to what you prefer.

Comment: I know what the featured tab means. But why do I get on the page? I am pretty sure its not the way it was some time ago. This is against [my] principle of least surprise. When I click on a tag, I'd like to find out about questions that are tagged "luatex" for example. And not "featured questions that are tagged luatex".

Comment: @Patrick: Sorry, I should have had a closer look at _who_ had asked the question. I do agree that this behaviour is somewhat surprising, and I've been surprised myself before. But this is the way the site behaves: It does remember which tab you were on, and it isn't shown in the URL. The same is with ordering of answers by "votes", "active" and "oldest": The site remembers the tab. And that's why I removed the "bug" tag.

Comment: The "funny" thing is that you can't even select "featured" from the available tabs/links.

Comment: That's also by design, as I just found out before leaving my previous comment: You can only select that tab if there's a featured question with the tag you're looking at.

Comment: I'd still call this behavior broken. But well, I give up ;-)

Comment: @Patrick: I'm not the one who invented this behaviour, and I'm not defending it. I'm just trying my best to explain it `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik Of course! I gave up because your explanations make sense. I am tempted to mark your answer as "correct", but I still have a feeling that this behavior surprises users (like me). So I hesitate to "close" this question.

Comment: @Patrick: You're always free to make feature-requests if you feel that the site can be improved somehow.

Comment: @Hendrik: OK, I'll make a feature request in a different question.